# How was the Ancient Egyptian name 'God is Gracious' written?

Tags: language, ancient-egypt

According to this article [Behind the Name: Ancient Egyptian Names Revealed](http://www.touregypt.net/featurestories/names.htm) there exists an Ancient Egyptian name meaning "God is Gracious".

What is that name and how is it written in Hieroglyphics? (Please can someone attach an image)

> (The article reads: Many ancient Egyptian names contained the name of a god. At times, the god may be assumed, so we have names that contain the phrase **"god is gracious"**, or "whom god loves", but here the term god undoubtedly refers not to an abstract deity but rather to a specific, assumed deity which might be a local god, or the god to whom the parents prayed. *Much of the time, the god was named.*

(I think it will contain the [NTR/NETER](http://www.eoht.info/m/page/Neter) hieroglyph?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The phrase is transliterated as "*mrwty*", or sometimes just "*mry*". It is most commonly translated as "*Beloved of ...*" or "*The well-beloved*".

This is the entry from Faulkner's [Concise Dictionary of Middle Egyptian](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=O2fdAQAACAAJ):

[image: mrwty]

So, for example, we have mry-imn ("Beloved of Amun"):

[image: mry-imn]

or, for a female, it would have an additional "t", becoming "mryt imn", as in [Meritamun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meritamen), the Great Royal Wife of Ramesses II:

[image: Meritamun]

- [Source - Wikipedia]

or the 17th dynasty princess, [Ahmose-Meritamun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmose-Meritamon_(17th_dynasty)):

[image: Ahmose-Meritamun]

- [Source - Wikipedia]

---

We do get the combination of "mrwty" and the hieroglyph nTr, denoting "the god":

[image: nTr]

This form is used as "mrwty nTr" in the [Hymn of Sehetep-ib-Ra](http://www.egyptomaniak.gr/Various%20Texts/Middle%20Kingdom%20Texts/MK%20Literature.html), for example.

---

The intransitive form of the verb *Htp* means "be gracious", so I suppose "*Htp nTr*":

[image: htp nTr]

might be read as "*[the] god is gracious*" (or the feminine "*Htp nTrt*" which could be "*[the] goddess is gracious*"). However, this phrase is more normally written as:

[image: htp nTr]

which is translated as "divine offerings" (the determinatives making all the difference there).

I have certainly never seen it in a name. Indeed, it would be surprising if it were. As the article you quoted notes:

> The essence of the individual was encapsulated in the name given to the child at birth.

So, we get Ramesses ("Man of Ra"), Thutmose ("Man of Thoth"), Seti ("Man of Seth"), Meriamun ("Beloved of Amun"), Nefertari Meritmut ("Beautiful companion, beloved of Mut"), etc.

The abstract idea that "god is gracious" doesn't really fit with the idea of the essence of the individual, and may well reflect modern politics at play in this case. Particularly if we consider the various audiences that the article was presumably written for (academic Egyptologists are not among them!).